# python time results not as expected: time.time() - time.time()

Tags: python

In playing around with the python execution of `time`, I found an odd behavior when calling `time.time()` twice within a single statement.  There is a very small processing delay in obtaining `time.time()` during statement execution.

E.g. **time.time() - time.time()**

If executed immediately in a perfect world, would compute in a result of 0.

However, in real world, this results in a very small number as there is an assumed delay in when the processor executes the first time.time() computation and the next. However, when running this same execution and comparing it to a variable computed in the same way, the results are skewed in one direction.

See the small code snippet below.
This also holds true for very large data sets

```
import time

counts = 300000

def at_once():
  first = 0
  second = 0
  x = 0
  while x < counts:
      x += 1
      exec_first = time.time() - time.time()
      exec_second = time.time() - time.time()

      if exec_first > exec_second:
          first += 1
      else:
          second += 1


print('1sts: %s' % first)
print('2nds: %s' % second)
```

prints:

```
1sts: 39630
2nds: 260370
```

Unless I have my logic incorrect, I would expect the results to very close to 50:50, but it does not seem to be the case. Is there anyone who could explain what causes this behavior or point out a potential flaw with the code logic that is making the results skewed in one direction?

Comment: Could it be that exec_first == exec_second? You if-else would add 1 to second in that case.

Comment: @kamses Quick test on my machine seems to indicate so: `1sts: 61627
2nds: 59123
neither: 179250`

Comment: @user10605163 That is much closer to 50-50, which looks to correct the expected behavior.

Comment: On my machine Python 2.7.15: `1sts: 37 2nds: 36 neither: 299927`

Comment: Testing on [ideone](https://ideone.com/OhzQtf) says that's not the whole story.

Comment: *the results are skewed in one direction* because your measurement is skewed in one direction.

Comment: ... when you are going to debug `exec_first` and `exec_second` they are often 0. So Python seems to be close to be perfect :)

Comment: @wim ignore me :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that `exec_first == exec_second`? Your if-else would add 1 to second in that case.

Try changing you if-else to something like:

```
if exec_first > exec_second:
    first += 1
elif exec_second > exec_first:
    second += 1
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Testing on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OhzQtf) displays a strong skew towards `first` with ties separated into a third category.

Comment: Testing on my local 3.6.3 build displays no such skew, though. I'm not sure what's going on in the Ideone tests.

Comment: I'm actually seeing the same skew you report for Ideone on my local 2.7.14 python build. No matter the order of variable declaration or variable name.

Comment: My local 2.7.13 doesn't display the skew. This is really weird.

Comment: Yeah, this has to be something under the hood? I'm at a loss. Based on the OP's reported output for his loop though, this code correction should correct the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You assign all of the ties to one category.  Try it with a middle ground:

```
import time

counts = 300000
first = 0 
second = 0 
same = 0

for _ in range(counts):
    exec_first = time.time() - time.time()
    exec_second = time.time() - time.time()

    if exec_first == exec_second:
        same += 1
    elif exec_first > exec_second:
        first += 1 
    else:
        second += 1 

print('1sts: %s' % first)
print('same: %s' % same)
print('2nds: %s' % second)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 so.py
1sts: 53099
same: 194616
2nds: 52285
$ python3 so.py
1sts: 57529
same: 186726
2nds: 55745
```

Also, I'm confused as to why you think that a function call might take 0 time.  Every invocation requires at least access to the system clock and copying that value to a temporary location of some sort.  This isn't free of overhead on any current computer.

Comment: I never expected it to be 0, if it was perfect no delay execution it should be expected to return 0.